# Wifi doesn't work - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, acer, aspire

Here is my problem:
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop Acer Aspire E1-530 two nights ago and it worked perfectly. I woke up next morning, turned on my laptop and my browser (Chromium) said that it couldn't connect to the server. So, I checked my WiFi and there was difference. WiFi icon was, i don't know how to explain (sorry for bad English), dinamic. Lines on the WiFi icon weren't full as they were night before. I hope you understand what I am trying to say. It lasted for a minut, maybe two and then Ubuntu said that the laptop was disconected from internet. All that repeats and repeats each time i try to connect on WiFi.
Any suggestions what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your computer might be a bit out of range to the Wifi signal. Try going a bit closer to the router.

Comment: I'm on the same place where WiFi worked perfectly couple nights ago. And also it works on my mobile phone. I think that laptop or Ubuntu is problem, but I don't know what.

Comment: Click on wifi icon in the panel. Go on connection information of something similar, and what is the strength of the wifi. Also, If you have a Live CD try going in live mode to see if the same problem is experienced.